# Unwind does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, unwind-segue

I'm studying Swift, I make course in DesignCode and now I'm trying to create an app to improve what I've learned.

So that is what I do:

- I created UIViewController and perform a segue to a UITableViewController;
- In the UITableViewController I embedded in with navigation bar where I create a 'Back' Bar Button Item;
- And I link this 'Back' to exit, performing a segue to unwind via 'Spring'.

When I click on this button I receive the following error:

```
2015-06-04 15:32:08.662 Vitrine[2883:67901] *** Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate _perform:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate.m:78
2015-06-04 15:32:08.676 Vitrine[2883:67901] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not find a view controller to execute unwinding for <UINavigationController: 0x7ae41540>'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0154d746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02f4ea97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0154d5da +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 138
    3   Foundation                          0x019c3720 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 118
    4   UIKit                               0x0253d3b4 -[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate _perform:] + 387
    5   UIKit                               0x0237c313 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 116
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02f647cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    7   UIKit                               0x01d72a90 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
    8   UIKit                               0x020f8bba -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 139
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02f647cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    10  UIKit                               0x01d72a90 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
    11  UIKit                               0x01d72a22 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    12  UIKit                               0x01eb318a -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
    13  UIKit                               0x01eb35a7 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
    14  UIKit                               0x01eb2811 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660
    15  UIKit                               0x01dcacfa -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
    16  UIKit                               0x01dcb7d6 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 792
    17  UIKit                               0x01d896d1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    18  UIKit                               0x01d99b08 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 21484
    19  UIKit                               0x01d6d337 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2300
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0146f06f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01464b7d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x014640d8 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01463a5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0146388b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x050c62c9 GSEventRunModal + 192
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x050c6106 GSEventRun + 104
    27  UIKit                               0x01d71106 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    28  Vitrine                             0x00076cd4 main + 180
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x0366bac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Regards,
Diogo Amaral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to, in the view you wanna get back for, create an IBAction like this:

```
@IBAction func back(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        //no code here, unless you want to do something when exiting
    }
```

And then, in the view you want to exit from, link your `barButtonItem` to the exit (the IBAction should appear there).

Answer (score 0):

To add standard Navigation and navigation bar you should use a `UINavigationController`. The `UINavigationController` will "wrap" the other views in the navigation flow (stack), and therfore you need not add any `UINavigationBar` on any views.

If implemented correctly `Back` is taken care of automagically by the `UINavigationController`.

[image]

Left arrow: *Inital View Controller* should point at the `UINavigationController`

1st segue: root view controller = First view controller that will show.

2nd segue: `show`. Trigger a `show` segue and the UINavigationController will push the next view. A back link will show for back navigation.

You can chain as many views as you need using the *show* segue, and you can have many `show` segues from one and the same view controller if needed.

UPDATE:

And if you really want to use the unwind segues for different reasons, here is an excellent explanation on how they work:

[What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

Comment: Thank you, it works but...
If want just present a modal, how I can do that? Because doing in this way, the Navigation always appears. 
Regards, Diogo Amaral

Comment: There is a `segue` called `present modally`. It will push a view controller "over" the current view controller. (Default animation, flying in from the bottom). Try it out, it's awesome. :)

Comment: And if I misunderstood the question, this would be how to dismiss it after you get on the screen: http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/02/19/dismissing-a-modal-view-using-a-storyboard-segue

Comment: I already insert a segue `present modally` but when I change the `presentation` of `default` to `over current context` the unwind does not work.

Comment: The way that @Gabriel Bitencourt gave me works perfectly, thank you man!